# How to avoid reduce_mean being an empty tensor in Keras or Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, debugging, keras

I use `reduce_mean` to get the mean value of `tensor_a`.
If `tensor_a` is an empty tensor, I get `nan` value.

```
tensor_a = K.variable([])
print(K.get_value(tf.reduce_mean(tensor_a)))
```

Output:

```
nan
```

However, if `tensor_a` is a empty tensor, I'd like to get zero instead of `nan` value. 
How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? Essentially as long as `tf.size(tensor_a)` is greater than 0, you'll get the `reduce_mean()` called. Otherwise, you get 0 out.

```
tensor_a = K.variable([])

print(
  K.get_value(
    tf.cond(
      tf.equal(tf.size(tensor_a), 0), 
      lambda : tf.constant(0.0), lambda: tf.reduce_mean(tensor_a)
    )
  )
)
```